# Cloudinary PHP: Fatal error: undefined function cloudinary_url()

Tags: php, cloud, cloudinary

i'm trying to use Cloudinary PHP. I downloaded the official github samples. (https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/tree/master/samples)

I've copied the SRC and SAMPLES folders and the autoload.php to my hosting FTP's root. ( i followed carefully the manual setup process, no using composer )

The directory structure on the server (PHP 7.3) is really simple:

```
WWWROOT:

- autoload.php
--- src/
--- samples/
---------- basic/
--------------- basic.php
--------------- settings.php
```

**I've correctly configured the settings.php** inside the basic folder with my Cloudinary account parameters.

Now, if i try to call the basic.php page, i get:

***PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function cloudinary_url() on basic.php:107***

This is line 107:

*`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo cloudinary_url('http://cloudinary.com/favicon.png', array('type' => 'fetch')); ?>"/>`*

So, why it's not recognizing that cloudinary_url function ?

Please, help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have **autoload.php** required in file **basic.php**?

```
require_once('../../autoload.php');
```

Comment: Yes, I've set autoload.php correctly, php is including that file. I don't know how to fix this error :-(

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when the path is incorrect. The `samples` directory is supposedly at the same level as where your `vendor` folder is located. So I would suggest to move the `samples` folder there and give it a try again.

Comment: ... is there supposed to be a "vendor" folder then ? I followed the instructions here:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_integration#manual_installation

So, I just copied the SRC FOLDER and AUTOLOAD.PHP ( and SAMPLES folder too ) directly inside my root folder. Aren't them enough to run Cloudinary correctly ?

As I said, I did a manual setup, didn't use Composer ( isn't the "vendor" folder a composer's thing ? )

Comment: You should use **Composer** when you are using thirdparty lib and then require autoload.php file from your vendor.

Answer (score 0):

They fixed it.

The problem was indeed a missing inclusion (of Helpers.php) inside the samples.

Please see: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/issues/192